# Likelihood of sampling each types from a population comprising many types?

Tags: probability

I have a total population size of 10,000 comprising 50 unique types which I assume are equally represented, i.e. their are 200 individuals per unique type in my population. 
 - How many samples would I need to take (without replacement) to ensure that I was x% (100%) confident of obtaining at least one representative of each unique type?
 - How many unique types could I expect to obtain if I only sampled 500 individuals (without replacement)?

Comment: The (complement of the) second question is rather easier than the first.  What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Are you interested only in analytical solutions, or numerical ones also? I can discern 3 questions:
1. How many samples would I need to be x% confident?
2. How many samples would I need to be 100% confident? (A much easier question!)
3. How many types would I expect to obtain with 500 samples?

Comment: I'm interested in an analytical formula and a solution to this specific question.  100% confidence would be better that nothing (or 95% confidence).  Replacement is not possible because we have to use the types as they are identified.

Comment: To be 100% confident, you'd need 9801 samples, since 9800 would leave open the possibility of all 200 of one type being excluded.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately my simple Excel spreadsheet is not able to work with such large numbers.

Comment: I assume this refers to my partial answer below? We can get round this using "manual" calculations for the probabilities P_t in the spreadsheet. To illustrate the general idea, take t=1, n=3. Then the formula simplifies to:
(9800 x 9799 x 9798) / (10000 x 9999 x 9998)
= (9800 / 10000) x (9799 / 9999) x (9798 / 9998).
Calculating it piece-wise like this works ok. There are minor rounding errors due to the presence of huge and tiny numbers in the cells.
I've created the spreadsheet and checked the results against a random number simulation. I get e.g. n=336 gives >95% confidence.

Comment: Happy to share the spreadsheet, not sure the best way of doing so, it's Libre Office.

Comment: And as regards the last part of the question, I think it's now fair to say with a sample of 500 the expected number of types obtained would be only marginally below 50. A counterintuitive result, I find, but the random number simulation seems to confirm it.

Comment: I tried to do this in Excel using a decision tree and simple numbers.  I see that for a population "s", number of unique variants "n" and number of unique sets "v" the the probability of selecting identical variants after x number of samples is P = v(n!/(s! - (s-(n-x))!) - then I got stumped.  If you could email me your spreadsheet that will help me to move forward.  david@mcelroyconsultingllc.com.  Nothing to do with consulting per se .... rather I'm doing some scientific experiments and want to figure out how many samples to take to be 95% confident of success.   Thanks.

Comment: I see that folks in our lab are using the formula P = 1 - e^(-N/V) or N = -V ln (1 - P) to generate the optimum sample number where P = probability, N = sample number and V = number of unique variants?

Comment: Okay - here's a general solution that gets you close enough for approximation purposes:  N = -V x ln (( 1- (P^1/V)), where V = number of alternative/unique variants, P = % confidence and N = number of samples to assay.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer (for the first part of the question):

Let $n$ be the size of the sample. Then there are $\left(\begin{matrix} 10000 \\ n \end{matrix}\right)$ possible samples, all equally likely.

Let $E_1$ be the event that type $1$ is unrepresented. There are $\left(\begin{matrix} 9800 \\ n \end{matrix}\right)$ possible samples in which type $1$ is unrepresented, so:

$$P(E_1) = \frac{\left(\begin{matrix} 9800 \\ n \end{matrix}\right)}{\left(\begin{matrix} 10000 \\ n \end{matrix}\right)}$$

Call this probability $p_1$. Similarly for all $2\le k\le 50$ we have $P(E_k) = p_1$ where $E_k$ is the event that type $k$ is unrepresented.

Now we are interested in the probability that at least one type is unrepresented (since that is $1$ minus the probability that every type is represented). Therefore would like to know:

$$P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup … \cup E_{50})$$

For this we can use a generalisation of the formula $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. This generalisation is the inclusion-exclusion principle as applied to probability, see the following article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion-exclusion_principle#In_probability

In this case we can use the fact that the probability that any two types are both unrepresented, for example $P(E_1 \cap E_2)$, is equal to

$$p_2 = \frac{\left(\begin{matrix} 9600 \\ n \end{matrix}\right)}{\left(\begin{matrix} 10000 \\ n \end{matrix}\right)}$$

And in general, the probability that any $t$ types are all unrepresented is

$$p_t = \frac{\left(\begin{matrix} 10000-200t \\ n \end{matrix}\right)}{\left(\begin{matrix} 10000 \\ n \end{matrix}\right)}$$

Therefore we can use the special case of the inclusion-exclusion principle in which the probability of the intersection depends only on the cardinality of the intersection (i.e. on what we are calling $t$). In that special case the formula for probability of the union is:

$$P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup … \cup E_{50}) = \sum_{t=1}^{50}(-1)^{t-1}\left(\begin{matrix} 50 \\ t \end{matrix}\right)p_t$$

Therefore the probability of obtaining at least one representative of each type is

$$1-\sum_{t=1}^{50}(-1)^{t-1}\left(\begin{matrix} 50 \\ t \end{matrix}\right)p_t$$

Where

$$p_t = \frac{\left(\begin{matrix} 10000-200t \\ n \end{matrix}\right)}{\left(\begin{matrix} 10000 \\ n \end{matrix}\right)}$$

We could then use trial and improvement to find the value of $n$ that would ensure $x$ percent confidence.